# How many three-digit numbers can be formed using digits {$1$, $6$, $9$, $9$, $9$,}?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

If I had $5$ *distinct* digits $(1,2,3,4,5)$ I would do it like so:

> $\frac{5!}{(5-3)!} = 60$

But I don't understand what to do if I have $3$ repeating digits

Comment: How many 3 digit numbers can you make using $\{1,6,9\}$? Using $\{1,9,9\}$? Using $\{6,9,9\}$? Using $\{9,9,9\}$? Add 'em up.

Comment: For a general approach we can use exponential generating functions, or "egf"s. I have recently answered a similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178425/number-of-strings-generatable/2178550#2178550). For your case you have an *egf* $1+x$ for each character "1" and "6" and an *egf* $1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!$ for the "9"s. Hence you expand $$(1+x)^2\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}\right)$$ and compute the coefficient of $x^3/3!$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make a decision tree, showing the options to pick $9$ (blue) or other (pink) at the earlier stages where it will have an effect on subsequent options; the last choice is green because that just represents the available choices. Then multiply down each branch and add:

$$2\cdot 1\cdot 1 + 2\cdot 1\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 2\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 1\cdot 3 = 2+4+4+3 = \fbox {13}$$

[image]

---

An **inclusion-exclusion** approach would be to regard this a choice with restrictions on how many $1$s and $6$s we're allowed.

The unrestricted choice would be $3^3=27$ options.

Excluding choices with excess $1$s involves any cases with two $1$s, $6$ cases, or three $1$s, $1$ case - in total $7$ cases to remove.

Excluding choices with excess $6$s likewise gives $7$ cases to remove.

Total valid choices then is $27-2\cdot 7=13$.

Comment: All of this is true, but I can't do this with big numbers (8-digit numbers, etc.). I need a logic which I can apply in all situations using permutations/combinations/variations. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @AverageBrick Added another approach.

Answer (score 2):

- First Number - $999$
- Second Number (Take all distinct digits) = $3$!
- Third Number (Take $2$ $9$'s) = $C(1,1) * C(3,2) * C(2,1)= 3$!

Total Numbers = $1 + 6 + 6 = 13$

---

$C(1,1)$ - How many repeating numbers are there ? Only $9$ is repeating and choose to include only that .

$C(3,2)$ - How many $9$'s are there ? How many are we using ?

$C(2,1)$ - After including $9$, only one place left . How many ways to fill that ?

Comment: Also a good answer. You could tighten up the third branch by saying (a) which digit is not a $9$? $\binom 31$ (b) which digit is it? $\binom 21$